# How do I display the index of one array if the input matches the index of another array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have to show the abbreviations of the provinces of my country when the user types in the name, or show the name when the user types in the province. I have created the 2 arrays so that the indexes match and I am trying to use a for loop to search through the arrays and once they find a match then display the other arrays same index in a textbox. It works only for the first index and even with the first index shows the else error message. What am I doing wrong?

```
string[] statenames = new string[9] { "Eastern Cape", "Free State", "Gauteng", "KwaZulu-Natal", "Limpopo", "Mpumalanga", "Northern Cape", "North-West", "Western Cape" };
string[] abbreviations = new string[9] { "EC", "FS", "GP", "KZN", "LP", "MP", "NC", "NW", "WC" };

private void btnLook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string name = txtName.Text;
        string abbreviation = txtAbbreviation.Text;
        if (rbtnAbbreviation.Checked == false && rbtnStateName.Checked == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select what you would like to look up", "Entry Error");
        }

        if (rbtnAbbreviation.Checked)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < statenames.Length; x++)
            {
                if (name == statenames[x])
                {
                    txtAbbreviation.Text = abbreviations[x];
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid province name", "Entry Error");
                    txtName.Focus();
                }
            }
        }

        if (rbtnStateName.Checked)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < abbreviations.Length; x++)
            {
                if (abbreviation == abbreviations[x])
                {
                    txtName.Text = statenames[x];
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid province abbreviation", "Entry Error");
                    txtAbbreviation.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically, instead of paired arrays you would use a Dictionary or make a class and have a single array/list of that class type. Paired arrays are an **antipattern** to avoid.

Comment: Of course it shows the 'else error message' - you have it *inside* the loop.  Show it only after you have performed the entire loop *and* nothing was found. **[How to use the awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: I did try to put it outside of the for loop but it wouldnt allow an else statement there? i also tried to do if(!name == state....) but that didn't work,

Comment: i haven't been taught about a dictionary yet (i'm a second year university student) so i assumed this is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a **break** to the if conditions. Once you find the name you want you get out of the loop.

```
if (abbreviation == abbreviations[x])
                {
                    txtName.Text = statenames[x];
                    break;
            }
```

in-order to prevent the loop from continue checking the rest of the array, and that's what cause the else to be triggered.